# MediaElement Set position in Pause mode

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone

I use this method to seek new position in my `MediaElement` :

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newSecond);
System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    mediaElement1.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newSecond);
});
```

When the user play video and then pause it and seek to new position the video frame stay in the previous frame.

And i want to know if it possible that when i seek to new position and the video is in pause mode so the frame will move to the new position and won't wait until i press play again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `MediaElement`s [`ScrubbingEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.scrubbingenabled.aspx) property to true

Comment: Can i use it in windows phone too? I don't found this property

Comment: Looks like windows phone doesn't support this property, did you ever find a solution to your problem?