# MediaElement.Position not reflecting on changes in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

I have a MediaElement whose position when set is not reflecting.

```
if(Playback.CanSeek)
   Playback.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,4);
```

Do note the MediaElement is currently paused and Autoplay turned on etc.
There are no errors but the line just does not change the Position property.

Also ran the code in Core Dispatcher, but still no luck.

Edit: Also Note this MediaElement is created from C# and not associated with XAML as it is in the ViewModel as a Library.

Thank you.

Comment: What does it plays? I recall there are some things which are can't be rewinded.

Comment: Its playing a simple mp3 file

Comment: Did you [set scrubbing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15053870/1997232) ?

Comment: This probably does not apply for a UWP MediaElement.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you would have to add your MediaElement object into XAML UI.

For example like the following code:

```
<Grid x:Name="root" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Button Content="set" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
MediaElement playback = new MediaElement();
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("test.mp3");
    if (file != null)
    {
        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        playback.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    }
    playback.Play();
    root.Children.Add(playback);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (playback.CanSeek)
    {
        playback.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would you suggest I handle this in the case of MVVM where my ViewModel has the MediaElement since most of the logic is there.

Comment: I'll see if I can send a dispatcher and work it in the Core Thread

Comment: @AbsoluteSith Why not put a MediaElement control on XAML, and bind source to it?

Comment: Cause I have my own custom control which I'm using as MediaElement control

Comment: The MediaElement still can play media file when it's created by code. I think it's unreasonable.